# How to use Binary column to JOIN in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am creating a dataflow in Azure Data Factory . I have to join two Data source on a column which is binary (VARBINARY(MAX)).
The validation shows me this error : Expression's type 'binary' is not compatible with left side expression's type 'binary'

How to JOIN using binary in ADF JOINS ?
[Validation Error on JOIN Binary column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GTUw.png)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using function hex()

JOIN on hex(column1) == hex(column2).